# Div with 6 divs inside aligned and stacked

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm trying to make a containing DIV that has 6 Divs inside. The far left and right are 25% wide and 100% high wile the middle 4 are all 25% wide 50% high and stacked on top of each other. Something like my crude drawing below:

```
-------------------------------------------
|          | Div 2    | Div 3   |         |
|   DIV 1  |          |         |         |
|          | All 4 25%| width   |         |
|25% width |__________| ________|  Div 6  |
|          |          |         | same as |
|100%      |    50%   | Height  |         |
| height   |          |         | Div 1   |
|          | Div 4    | Div 5   |         |
-------------------------------------------
```

I keep getting close but this has me stumped. Thanks!

Comment: Show us your coding attempts.

Comment: Itay, here it is http://jsfiddle.net/rplace/47HUH/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put DIVs 2-5 into a container DIV, then float DIVs 1-6 as well as the container DIV, you should be in good shape.  For example, your HTML could look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tall">
        ONE
    </div>
    <div class="middle_container">
        <div class="short">
            TWO
        </div>
        <div class="short">
            THREE
        </div>
            <div class="short">
            FOUR
        </div>
        <div class="short">
            FIVE
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tall">
        SIX
    </div>
</div>
```

And your CSS like this:

```
.container {
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
}

.tall {
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ffffaa;
}

.middle_container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#bbbbff;
}

.short {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float:left;
}
```

This Fiddle shows the result in action:  http://jsfiddle.net/y3QDt/.  I've colored the DIVs inside and outside of the container differently in hopes of making it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: That works too...thanks. I had overlooked the middle container. Any way to do it without, so I can learn a bit?

Comment: I don't believe so, unless you want to make use of `inline-block` as was suggested in Vucko's answer.  However, `inline-block` has the small disadvantage of not being fully supported by IE 7 and earlier, so I stay away from it in cases like this where you can do so without bloating your code much.

Answer (score 5):

Example:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="large" style="background:red;"></div><!--
    --><div class="large">
    <div class="box" style="background:yellow;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background:green;"></div>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="large">
    <div class="box" style="background:black;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background:aqua;"></div>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="large" style="background:blue;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
html, body, .parent {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}

.large{
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    display:inline-block;
}

.box{
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsYb3/1)

Note: in the fiddle I use [Eric Meyer’s “Reset CSS” 2.0](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: Nice solution.. although it would be nice if you didn't have to use the HTML `inline-block` comment hack..

Comment: Tnx. It's not a hack, just a way to get rid of the _whitespace_ without making the code "ugly".

Comment: @Vucko, thanks that seems to do the trick I had not thought about the two divs around the blocks of 4. Can you or someone else tell me if I was on track with this http://jsfiddle.net/rplace/47HUH/1/